# How to find the most frequently occurring character in a string with Java?

Tags: java, algorithm, histogram

Given a paragraph as input, find the most frequently occurring character. Note that the case of the character does not matter. If more than one character has the same maximum occurring frequency, return all of them
I was trying this question but I ended up with nothing. Following is the code that I tried but it has many errors I am unable to correct:

```
public class MaximumOccuringChar {

    static String testcase1 = "Hello! Are you all fine? What are u doing today? Hey Guyz,Listen! I have a plan for today.";

    public static void main(String[] args) 
    {
        MaximumOccuringChar test = new MaximumOccuringChar();
        char[] result = test.maximumOccuringChar(testcase1);
        System.out.println(result);
    }

    public char[] maximumOccuringChar(String str) 
    {
        int temp = 0;
        int count = 0;
        int current = 0;

        char[] maxchar = new char[str.length()];

        for (int i = 0; i < str.length(); i++) 
        {
            char ch = str.charAt(i);

            for (int j = i + 1; j < str.length(); j++) 
            {
                char ch1 = str.charAt(j);

                if (ch != ch1) 
                {
                    count++;
                }
            }

            if (count > temp) 
            {
                temp = count;
                maxchar[current] = ch;
                current++;
            }
        }
        return maxchar;
    }
}
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to return longest sequence of chars in a string in java?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21748970/how-to-return-longest-sequence-of-chars-in-a-string-in-java)

Comment: OK, what's your question?

Comment: This is a typical case for a `Map<String, Integer>` where keys are characters, and thus limited in number, and values are frequencies. Solution is O(N) -- one scan to populate the map and one scan through a tiny map to find the highest frequency.

Comment: I have to find out the most frequently occuring alphabet in the para.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You already got your answer here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/21749133/1661864

It's a most easy way I can imagine.

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Map;

public class MaximumOccurringChar {

    static final String TEST_CASE_1 = "Hello! Are you all fine? What are u doing today? Hey Guyz,Listen! I have a plan for today. Help!";


    public static void main(String[] args) {
        MaximumOccurringChar test = new MaximumOccurringChar();
        List<Character> result = test.maximumOccurringChars(TEST_CASE_1, true);
        System.out.println(result);
    }


    public List<Character> maximumOccurringChars(String str) {
        return maximumOccurringChars(str, false);
    }

    // set skipSpaces true if you want to skip spaces
    public List<Character> maximumOccurringChars(String str, Boolean skipSpaces) {
        Map<Character, Integer> map = new HashMap<>();
        List<Character> occurrences = new ArrayList<>();
        int maxOccurring = 0;

        // creates map of all characters
        for (int i = 0; i < str.length(); i++) {
            char ch = str.charAt(i);

            if (skipSpaces && ch == ' ')      // skips spaces if needed
                continue;

            if (map.containsKey(ch)) {
                map.put(ch, map.get(ch) + 1);
            } else {
                map.put(ch, 1);
            }

            if (map.get(ch) > maxOccurring) {
                maxOccurring = map.get(ch);         // saves max occurring
            }
        }

        // finds all characters with maxOccurring and adds it to occurrences List
        for (Map.Entry<Character, Integer> entry : map.entrySet()) {
            if (entry.getValue() == maxOccurring) {
                occurrences.add(entry.getKey());
            }
        }

        return occurrences;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 5):

Why don't you simply use `N` letter buckets (`N`=number of letters in alphabet) ? Just go along the string and increment the corresponding letter bucket. Time complexity `O(n)`, space complexity `O(N)`

Answer (score 2):

This method allows you to find the most frequently occurring character in a string:

```
  public char maximumOccuringChar(String str) {
    return str.chars()
            .mapToObj(x -> (char) x)                  // box to Character
            .collect(groupingBy(x -> x, counting()))  // collect to Map<Character, Long>
            .entrySet().stream()
            .max(comparingByValue())                  // find entry with largest count
            .get()                                    // or throw if source string is empty
            .getKey();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class MaximumOccurringChar{

static String testcase1 = "Hello! Are you all fine? What are u doing today? Hey Guyz,Listen! I have a plan for today.";

public static void main(String[] args) {
    MaximumOccurringChar test = new MaximumOccurringChar();
   String result = test.maximumOccuringChar(testcase1);
    System.out.println(result);
}

public String maximumOccuringChar(String str) {
    int temp = 0;
    int count = 0;
    int current = 0;
    int ind = 0;
    char[] arrayChar = {'a','b' , 'c', 'd', 'e', 'f', 'g', 'h', 'i', 'j', 'k', 'l', 'm', 'n', 'o', 'p', 'q', 'r', 's', 't', 'u', 'v', 'w', 'x', 'y', 'z'};
    int[] numChar = new int[26];
    char ch;
    String s="";
    str = str.toLowerCase();
    for (int i = 0; i < 26; i++) {
        count = 0;
        for (int j = 0; j < str.length(); j++) {
            ch = str.charAt(j);
            if (arrayChar[i] == ch) {
                count++;
            }
        }
        numChar[i] = count++;
    }
    temp = numChar[0];

    for (int i = 1; i < numChar.length; i++) {
        if (temp < numChar[i]) {
            temp = numChar[i];

            ind = i;
            break;
        }
    }
       System.out.println(numChar.toString());
        for(int c=0;c<26;c++)
        {
            if(numChar[c]==temp)
            s+=arrayChar[c]+" ";


        }


    return s;

   }
   }
```

Comment: this code has bugs :( I tested it just using the word 'Hello' and it return 'h e o'

Answer (score 0):

Algorithm:-

1. Copying the String character by character to LinkedHashMap.

   - If its a new character then insert new character , 1.
   - If character is already present in the LinkedHashMap then update the value                     by incrementing by 1.
2. Iterating over the entry one by one and storing it in a Entry object.

   - If value of key stored in entry object is greater than or equal to current entry then do nothing
   - Else, store new entry in the Entry object
3. After looping through, simply print the key and value from Entry object.

public class Characterop {

```
public void maxOccur(String ip)
{

    LinkedHashMap<Character, Integer> hash = new LinkedHashMap();
    for(int i = 0; i<ip.length();i++)
    {
        char ch = ip.charAt(i);
        if(hash.containsKey(ch))
        {
            hash.put(ch, (hash.get(ch)+1));

        }
        else
        {
            hash.put(ch, 1);
        }
    }

   //Set set = hash.entrySet();
   Entry<Character, Integer> maxEntry = null;
   for(Entry<Character,Integer> entry : hash.entrySet())
   {
      if(maxEntry == null)
      {
          maxEntry = entry;
      }

      else if(maxEntry.getValue() < entry.getValue())
      {
          maxEntry = entry;
      }
   }
    System.out.println(maxEntry.getKey());


}
public static void main(String[] args) {
    Characterop op = new Characterop();
    op.maxOccur("AABBBCCCCDDDDDDDDDD");
}
```

}

Answer (score 0):

The Big O below solution is just o(n). Please share your opinion on it.

```
    public class MaxOccuringCahrsInStr {

        /**
         * @param args
         */
        public static void main(String[] args) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            String str = "This is Sarthak Gupta";

            printMaxOccuringChars(str);

        }

        static void printMaxOccuringChars(String str) {
            char[] arr = str.toCharArray();
            /* Assuming all characters are ascii */
            int[] arr1 = new int[256];
            int maxoccuring = 0;

            for (int i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
                if (arr[i] != ' ') { // ignoring space
                    int val = (int) arr[i];
                    arr1[val]++;
                    if (arr1[val] > maxoccuring) {
                        maxoccuring = arr1[val];
                    }
                }

            }

            for (int k = 0; k < arr1.length; k++) {
                if (maxoccuring == arr1[k]) {
                    char c = (char) k;
                    System.out.print(c + " ");

                }

            }

        }

    }
```

Answer (score 0):

```
function countString(ss)
        {
            var maxChar='';
            var maxCount=0;
            for(var i=0;i<ss.length;i++)
            {
                var charCount=0;
                var localChar=''
                for(var j=i+1;j<ss.length;j++)
                {
                    if(ss[i]!=' ' && ss[i] !=maxChar)
                    if(ss[i]==ss[j])
                    {
                        localChar=ss[i];
                        ++charCount;
                    }
                }
                if(charCount>maxCount)
                {
                    maxCount=charCount;
                    maxChar=localChar;
                }
            }
            alert(maxCount+""+maxChar)
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

Another way to solve it. A simpler one.

```
public static void main(String[] args) {

    String str= "aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaabbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbcddddeeeeee";
    String str1 = "dbc";

    if(highestOccuredChar(str) != ' ')
    System.out.println("Most Frequently occured Character ==>  " +Character.toString(highestOccuredChar(str)));
    else
        System.out.println("The String doesn't have any character whose occurance is more than 1");
}

private static char highestOccuredChar(String str) {

    int [] count = new int [256];

    for ( int i=0 ;i<str.length() ; i++){
        count[str.charAt(i)]++;
    }

    int max = -1 ;
    char result = ' ' ;

    for(int j =0 ;j<str.length() ; j++){
        if(max < count[str.charAt(j)] && count[str.charAt(j)] > 1) {
            max = count[str.charAt(j)];
            result = str.charAt(j);
        }
    }

    return result;

}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
public void countOccurrence(String str){
    int length = str.length();
    char[] arr = str.toCharArray();
    HashMap<Character, Integer> map = new HashMap<>();
    int max = 0;

    for (char ch : arr) {
        if(ch == ' '){
            continue;
        }
        if (map.containsKey(ch)) {
            map.put(ch, map.get(ch) + 1);
        } else {
            map.put(ch, 1);
        }
    }

    Set<Character> set = map.keySet();

    for (char c : set) {
        if (max == 0 || map.get(c) > max) {
            max = map.get(c);
        }
    }

    for (Character o : map.keySet()) {
        if (map.get(o).equals(max)) {
            System.out.println(o);
        }
    }
    System.out.println("");
}

public static void main(String[] args) {
    HighestOccurence ho = new HighestOccurence();

    ho.countOccurrence("aabbbcde");
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
public void stringMostFrequentCharacter() {
    String str = "My string lekdcd dljklskjffslk akdjfjdkjs skdjlaldkjfl;ak adkj;kfjflakj alkj;ljsfo^wiorufoi$*#&$ *******";
    char[] chars = str.toCharArray(); //optionally - str.toLowerCase().toCharArray();
    int unicodeMaxValue = 65535;    // 4 bytes
    int[] charCodes = new int[unicodeMaxValue];
    for (char c: chars) {
        charCodes[(int)c]++;
    }
    int maxValue = 0;
    int maxIndex = 0;
    for (int i = 0; i < unicodeMaxValue; i++) {
        if (charCodes[i] > maxValue) {
            maxValue = charCodes[i];
            maxIndex = i;
        }
    }
    char maxChar = (char)maxIndex;
    System.out.println("The most frequent character is >" + maxChar + "<  -  # of times: " + maxValue);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

For Simple String Manipulation, this program can be done as:

```
package abc;
import java.io.*;

public class highocc 
{
        public static void main(String args[])throws IOException
        {
            BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(System.in));
            System.out.println("Enter any word : ");
            String str=in.readLine();
            str=str.toLowerCase();
            int g=0,count,max=0;;
            int ar[]=new int[26];
            char ch[]={'a','b','c','d','e','f','g','h','i','j','k','l','m','n','o','p','q','r','s','t','u','v','w','x','y','z'};
                for(int i=0;i<ch.length;i++)
                {
                    count=0;
                    for(int j=0;j<str.length();j++)
                     {
                        char ch1=str.charAt(j);
                        if(ch[i]==ch1)
                            count++;
                     }
                   ar[i]=(int) count;
                }
                max=ar[0];
                for(int j=1;j<26;j++)
                {
                    if(max<ar[j])
                        {
                            max=ar[j];
                            g=j;
                        }
                }
                System.out.println("Maximum Occurence is "+max+" of character "+ch[g]);
           } 
}
```

Sample Input1: Pratik is a good Programmer

Sample Output1: Maximum Occurence is 3 of character a

Sample Input2: hello WORLD

Sample Output2: Maximum Occurence is 3 of character l

Answer (score 0):

```
maxOccu m = new maxOccu();
String str = "moinnnnaaooooo";
char[] chars = str.toCharArray();
Arrays.sort(chars);
str = new String(chars);
System.out.println(str);
m.maxOccurence(str);

void maxOccurence(String str) {
    char max_char = str.charAt(0),
    cur_char,
    prev = str.charAt(0);
    int cur_count = 0,
    max_count = 0,
    n;
    n = str.length();
    for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) {
        cur_char = str.charAt(i);
        if (cur_char != prev) cur_count = 0;
        if (str.charAt(i) == cur_char) {
            cur_count++;
        }
        if (cur_count > max_count) {
            max_count = cur_count;
            max_char = cur_char;
        }
        prev = cur_char;
    }
    System.out.println(max_count + "" + max_char);
}
```

Comment: algorithm; 1.first we sort the string   2.then compare cur_char with the prevoius character if both matches then then increase cur_count. And is cur_count>max_count then cur_char is the Max_char    3.if cur_char != prev we start cur_count from 0

Answer (score 0):

```
public class HigestOccurredCharTest {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        System.out.println("Enter the char string to check higest occurrence");
        Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);
        String str = scan.next();
        if(str != null && !str.isEmpty()){
            Map<Character, Integer> map = countOccurrence(str);
            getHigestOccurrenceChar(map);
        }else{
            System.out.println("enter valid string");
        }
    }

    public static Map<Character, Integer> countOccurrence(String str){
         char strArr[] = str.toCharArray();
         Map<Character, Integer> map = new HashMap<Character , Integer>();
         for (Character ch : strArr) {
            if(map.containsKey(ch)){
                map.put(ch, map.get(ch)+1);
            }else{
                map.put(ch, 1);
            }
        }
        return map;
    }

    public static void getHigestOccurrenceChar(Map<Character, Integer> map){
        Character ch = null;
        Integer no = 0;
         Set<Entry<Character, Integer>> entrySet = map.entrySet();
         for (Entry<Character, Integer> entry : entrySet) {
             if(no != 0 && ch != null){
                 if(entry.getValue() > no){
                     no = entry.getValue();
                     ch = entry.getKey();
                 }
             }else{
                 no = entry.getValue();
                  ch = entry.getKey();
             }


        }
         System.out.println(ch+ " Higest occurrence char is "+ no);
    }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try Like that:-

```
        string inputString = "COMMECEMENT";
        List<Tuple<char, int>> allCharListWithLength = new List<Tuple<char, int>>();
        List<char> distinchtCharList = inputString.Select(r => r).Distinct().ToList();
        for (int i = 0; i < distinchtCharList.Count; i++)
        {
            allCharListWithLength.Add(new Tuple<char, int>(distinchtCharList[i], inputString.Where(r => r ==
            distinchtCharList[i]).Count()));
        }
        Tuple<char, int> charWithMaxLength = allCharListWithLength.Where(r => r.Item2 == allCharListWithLength.Max(x => x.Item2)).FirstOrDefault();
```

Answer (score 0):

Question: Frequently occurring Character in a String

Method 1: Using HashMap

```
public class t1{

    public static void main(String a[]){
Map<Character, Integer> map = new HashMap<>();
String a1 = "GiinnniiiiGiiinnnnnaaaProtijayi";
 for(char ch : a1.toCharArray()) {map.put(ch, map.getOrDefault(ch,0)+1);}//for
        System.out.println(map);

 char maxchar = 0 ;
 int maxvalue = Collections.max(map.values());
 System.out.println("maxvalue => " + maxvalue);
 for(   Entry<Character,Integer> entry  : map.entrySet()) {
     if(entry.getValue() == maxvalue) {

         System.out.println("most frequent Character => " + entry.getKey());
     }
 }//for

    }
}
```

Method 2 : Using count of alphabets in Python

```
str = "GiinnniiiiGiiinnnnnaaaProtijayi";

count = [0]*256
maxcount= -1
longestcharacter ="" 

    # Traversing through the string and maintaining the count of
    # each character
for ch in str:count[ord(ch)] += 1;

for ch in str:
    if( maxcount < count[ord(ch)] ):
        maxcount = count[ord(ch)]
        longestcharacter = ch


print(longestcharacter) 
print(maxcount)
```

IN Java :

```
public class t1{

   public static void main(String[] args) {
     String  a = "GiinnniiiiGiiinnnnnaaaProtijayi";
     int[] count = new int[256];
     for (int i = 0; i < a.length(); i++) {
        char ch = a.charAt(i);
        count[ch] +=1;
    }//for

     int maxcount = -1 ;
     char longest = 0 ;
     for( char ch : a.toCharArray()) {
         if(count[ch] > maxcount) {
              maxcount = count[ch];
              longest = ch ;
         }//if

     }//for
     System.out.println(longest);
     System.out.println(maxcount);



}//main
}
```

Method 3: Using collections.Counter().most_common()

```
import collections


a = "GiinnniiiiGiiinnnnnaaaProtijayi";
fullDictionary = collections.Counter(a).most_common()
FirstElementWithCount = fullDictionary[0]
print(FirstElementWithCount)
FirstElementWithoutCount = FirstElementWithCount[0]
print(FirstElementWithoutCount)
```

Method 4: Using sorted and key = lambda ch : ch[1]

```
a = "GiinnniiiiGiiinnnnnaaaProtijayi";

d = {}

for ch in a: d[ch] = d.get(ch, 0) + 1
fullDictionary = sorted(d.items(), key=lambda ch :ch[1], reverse=True)

print(fullDictionary)

FirstElement = fullDictionary[0][0]
print(FirstElement)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
package com.practice.ArunS;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Collections;
import java.util.Comparator;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Map;
import java.util.Map.Entry;
import java.util.TreeMap;

public class HighestFrequencyElement {
    /*
     * CONTENTSERV=N(2),T(2),E(2) SearchSort=S(2),r(2)
     * HighestFrequencyElement=E(5)
     */
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        String str = "CONTENTSERV";
        findHighestFrequencyElement(str);

    }

    private static void findHighestFrequencyElement(String str) {
        System.out.println("Original String:" + str);
        Map<String, Integer> myMap = new TreeMap<String, Integer>();

        char[] ch = str.toCharArray();
        for (int i = 0; i < str.length(); i++) {
            if (myMap.containsKey(Character.toString(ch[i]))) {
                Integer value = myMap.get(Character.toString(ch[i]));
                myMap.replace(Character.toString(ch[i]), ++value);
            } else {
                myMap.put(Character.toString(ch[i]), 1);
            }
        } // end of foor loop

        Comparator<Entry<String, Integer>> valueComparator = new Comparator<Entry<String, Integer>>() {

            @Override
            public int compare(Entry<String, Integer> e1, Entry<String, Integer> e2) {
                Integer v1 = e1.getValue();
                Integer v2 = e2.getValue();
                return v2-v1;
            }
        };

        // Sort method needs a List, so let's first convert Set to List in Java
        List<Entry<String, Integer>> listOfEntries = new ArrayList<Entry<String, Integer>>(myMap.entrySet());

        // sorting HashMap by values using comparator
        Collections.sort(listOfEntries, valueComparator);
        for(int i=0;i<listOfEntries.size();i++){
            if(listOfEntries.get(0).getValue()==listOfEntries.get(i).getValue()){
                System.out.println(listOfEntries.get(i));
            }
        }

    }//end of method

}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
    import java.util.Arrays;
    import java.util.Collections;

    import java.util.Comparator;
    import java.util.function.Predicate;
    import java.util.stream.Collectors;

public class Answers {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        String input1 = "Hello! Are you all fine? What are u doing today? Hey Guyz,Listen! I have a plan for today.";
        String[] arin = input1.split("");
        Predicate<String> checkIfValidChar = str -> ((str.charAt(0) >= '0' && str.charAt(0) <= '9')
                || (str.charAt(0) >= 'a' && str.charAt(0) <= 'z')
                || (str.charAt(0) >= 'A' && str.charAt(0) <= 'Z'));
        String maxChar = Arrays.stream(arin).max(Comparator.comparing(i -> Arrays.stream(arin).filter(j -> {
            return i.equalsIgnoreCase(j) && checkIfValidChar.test(j);
        }).count())).get();

        int count = Collections.frequency(Arrays.asList(arin), maxChar);
        System.out.println(Arrays.stream(arin).filter(i -> {
            return Collections.frequency(Arrays.asList(arin), i) == count && checkIfValidChar.test(i);
        }).collect(Collectors.toSet()));
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I see many answers that are unnecessarily convoluted, import tons of stuff or use a cannon to shoot a mosquito ( the accepted answer uses an HashTable ).

Here a simple solution:

```
public List<Character> mostFrequentLetter(String message) {
  var m = message
      .replaceAll("[^a-z]", "")
      .toLowerCase();

  int[] count = new int[26]; 
  for(var c : m.toCharArray()){
    int i = ((int)c)-97;
    count[i]++;
  }
  var max_i = 0; // index of the most frequent letter
  var max_c = count[max_i]; // count of the most frequent letter
  var max = new ArrayList<Character>(3); // list containing letters with the same frequency
  for(int i = 1; i < 26; ++i){
    if (count[i] >= max_c){
      max_i = i;
      char c = (char)(max_i + 97);
      if(count[i]!=max_c){
        max.clear();
        max_c = count[i];
      }
      max.add(c);
    }
  }
  return max;
}
```

Comment: 97 is the integer value of the 'a' character.

Answer (score 0):

Here **str** will be the given string. This is Javascript code

```
function maxCharacter(str){
let str1 = str; let reptCharsCount=0; let ele='';let maxCount=0;
let charArr = str1.split('');
for(let i=0; i< str1.length; i++){
    reptCharsCount=0;
    for(let j=0; j< str1.length; j++){
        if(str1[i] === str1[j]) {
            reptCharsCount++;
        }
    }

    if(reptCharsCount > maxCount) {
        ele = str1[i];
        maxCount = reptCharsCount; 
    }
}
return ele;
```

}

Answer (score 0):

Although all the answers are correct posting my way of doing it

> /*Question: For the given string such as "aabbbbbcc" print the longest occurring character,
>   index and number of times it occurs.
>   Ex:
>    "longest occurring character is b and length is 5 at index 2".*/

```
class Codechef {
public static void main (String[] args) {
    String problem = "aabbbbbcc";
    Map<Character,Temp> map = new HashMap<>();
    for(int i = 0; i < problem.length(); i++){
  if (map.containsKey(problem.charAt(i))) {
    map.get(problem.charAt(i)).incrementCount();
  } else {
    map.put(problem.charAt(i), new Temp(i, 1, problem.charAt(i)));
  }
    }

    List<Map.Entry<Character, Temp>> listOfValue = new LinkedList<Map.Entry<Character, Temp>>(map.entrySet());
    Comparator<Map.Entry<Character, Temp>> comp = (val1, val2) -> (val1.getValue().getCount() < val2.getValue().getCount() ? 1: -1);
    Collections.sort(listOfValue, comp);
    Temp tmp = listOfValue.get(0).getValue();
    System.out.println("longest occurring character is "+ tmp.getStr()+ " and length is " + tmp.getCount()+ " at index "+ tmp.getIndex());

}}
```

And then created one Model class to keep these values

```
class Temp {
Integer index;
Integer count;
Character str;
public Temp(Integer index, Integer count, Character str ){
    this.index = index;
    this.count = count;
    this.str = str;
}
public void incrementCount(){
    this.count++;
}
public Integer getCount(){
    return count;
}
public Character getStr(){
    return str;
}
public Integer getIndex(){
    return index;
}}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
        import java.util.HashMap;
        import java.util.Map;
        import java.util.Set;
        import java.util.Map.Entry;

        public class Maxchar {

            public static void main(String[] args) {

                String str = "vaquar khan.";
                // System.out.println();
                System.out.println(maxChar(str));
                String testcase1 = "Hello! Are you all fine? What are u doing today? Hey Guyz,Listen! I have a plan for today.";
                System.out.println(maxChar(testcase1));

            }

            private static char maxChar(String str) {

                if (null == str)
                    return ' ';

                char[] charArray = str.replaceAll("\s+", "").toCharArray();
                //

                Map<Character, Integer> maxcharmap = new HashMap<Character, Integer>();
                //
                for (char c : charArray) {
                    if (maxcharmap.containsKey(c)) {
                        maxcharmap.put(c, maxcharmap.get(c) + 1);
                    } else {
                        maxcharmap.put(c, 1);
                    }
                    // Inside map we have word count
                    // System.out.println(maxcharmap.toString());
                }

                //
                //

                Set<Entry<Character, Integer>> entrySet = maxcharmap.entrySet();
                int count = 0;
                char maxChar = 0;
                //
                for (Entry<Character, Integer> entry : entrySet) {
                    if (entry.getValue() > count) {
                        count = entry.getValue();
                        maxChar = entry.getKey();
                    }
                }

                System.out.println("Maximum Occurring char and its count :");
                System.out.println(maxChar + " : " + count);

                return maxChar;
            }

        }
```

Answer (score 0):

```
import java.util.*;

import java.util.stream.*;

class MaxOccur{
     
    public static void main(String[] args){
        
        String str = "sfowfjalkfaeffawkefjweajjwjegjoweeowe";
        maxOcc(str);
    
    }

    public static void maxOcc(String s){
        
       ArrayList<Character> arr = (ArrayList<Character>) s.chars().mapToObj(e ->(char)e).collect(Collectors.toList());

        HashSet<Character> hs = new HashSet<>(arr);

        int max = 0;
        int f = 0;
        String answer = "";

        for(Character ch : hs){
        
            f = Collections.frequency(arr,ch);
            if(f>max){
                max = f;
                answer = ch;
            }

            System.out.println(ch + " occurs " + max + " times, the maximum");
    }
}
```

In above, I'm using streams. Following are the steps:

1. Converting string's characters to arraylist using streams.
2. Making a hashset (discards all duplicate occurences of characters) using the arrayList created in step 1.
3. Use Collections.frequency to count occurence of each character in arrayList.
4. It's not the easiest solution, neither is it really adorable! But, it makes use of streams, something which i recently started learning and wanted to apply. I'm no adept in using streams, but they are beautiful. I've learnt most of them here on stackoverflow, and i'm so grateful. :)

Answer (score 0):

If you're open to 3rd party libraries you could use the [Bag](https://github.com/eclipse/eclipse-collections/blob/master/docs/guide.md#-bag) type from [Eclipse Collections](https://www.eclipse.org/collections/) and select the top occurrences.

```
public char[] maxOccurringChar(String s) {
    MutableCharBag bag = CharBags.mutable.of(s.toCharArray());
    MutableList<CharIntPair> maxOccurringCharsWithCounts = bag.topOccurrences(1);
    MutableCharList maxOccurringChars = maxOccurringCharsWithCounts.collectChar(CharIntPair::getOne);
    return maxOccurringChars.toArray();
}
```

Note in this example we used the primitive collections to avoid boxing of the `char` and `int` types.

Answer (score 0):

Map the chars to their occurrence then query entries for the max value and get its key, note this will return the first char that has the highest occurrence

```
"abc".chars().mapToObj(c -> (char) c)
                .collect(Collectors.groupingBy(Function.identity(),Collectors.counting()))
                .entrySet()
                .stream()
                .max(Comparator.comparingLong(Map.Entry::getValue))
                .get()
                .getKey();
```

Answer (score 0):

Here I am posting the answer by using HashMap

```
public class maximumOccurrence {

    
    public static Map<Character,Integer> maximumOccurence(String s) {
        
        char maxchar='';
        int maxint=0;
        Map<Character,Integer> map = new HashMap<Character, Integer>();
        char strAtt[]= s.toCharArray();
        for(Character ch : strAtt) {
            if(map.containsKey(ch)) {
                map.put(ch, map.get(ch)+1);
            }else {
                map.put(ch,1);
            }
            
            
        }
        
        for(Map.Entry<Character,Integer> entry : map.entrySet()) {
            System.out.println(entry.getKey() + "/" + entry.getValue());
            if(maxint<entry.getValue()) {
                maxint=entry.getValue();
                maxchar=entry.getKey();
            }
        }
        System.out.println("Character repeated ="+maxchar+" it's value is:"+maxint);
            
        
        return map;
    }
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
         String s= "uuuiiiiiiiiiiioooooopp";
         System.out.println(maximumOccurence(s));
    }

}
```